# swift date and time ios

Tags: ios, swift

I need to retrieve the date and time using swift in these formats.

```
2014-09-19
16:43:00.0
```

NSDate() gives the date and time together, and the time is in the wrong format, does anyone know how to get these separately and have the time in the format shown above.

Comment: If you are seeing this in the console it's expected behaviour. If you want to have your own format for display then you need to pass it through an nsdateformatter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do the trick:

```
let date = NSDate()

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
timeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss.S"

println(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date))
println(timeFormatter.stringFromDate(date))
```

Comment: No localisation makes me a sad 

Answer (score 1):

To format the date, use [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/index.html).

Comment: NSDateFormatter gives 5 different styles, but they all do not conform to the format above.

Comment: @AbubakarMoallim - NSDateFormatter has a virtually infinite number of styles.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, there is documentation on how to specify a format.  It's my least favorite thing to read.  [Good luck](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: I find [the documentation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) to be quite interesting, and I refer to it at least once a week.

Answer (score 1):

What are you using these two strings for? If you're using the for internal purposes (timestamping transactions, adding sorting fields to databases, submitting ISO 8601 / RFC 3339 date to web service), you generally would want to make sure that you also:

- Use GMT/UTC; and
- Specify the locale

Thus, that might yield:

```
let date = NSDate()
let timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
let locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = timeZone
dateFormatter.locale = locale
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
timeFormatter.timeZone = timeZone
timeFormatter.locale = locale
timeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss.S"

println(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date))
println(timeFormatter.stringFromDate(date))
```

The [Technical Q&A QA1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html) document discusses this within the context of ISO 8601 / RFC 3339 dates used on the Internet, but the underly concepts are equally applicable whenever you use these dates for internal purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code -

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let d = NSDate()
    let s = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(d)
    println(s)
```

Comment: Perfect. That works for the date, how about the time?